# Cheapest way of doing max() on absolute values, but have max() preserve sign?

Tags: math, optimization, comparison, glsl, max

I have a 3-vector, let's say

```
v = vec3(-4, 2, 3)
```

I would like to do a max on the absolute values of the components, so the equivalent of:

```
max(abs(v[0]), max(abs(v[1]), abs(v[2]))) == 4
```

However, I have a requirement that I need to preserve the sign.  So for example:

```
magic_max(v[0], magic_max(v[1], v[2])) == -4.
```

It's a trivial problem if I use conditional branching, but I'm trying to do this in as few operations as possible, and avoid branching.  Any ideas on where to look?  Maybe there's some bit-shifting magic that can be done?

Comment: Can't you leave such low-level optimizations to the compiler?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't trust my compiler to optimize it.  It is a GLSL bytecode compiler that goes straight to my GPU, and unfortunately I don't have access to any intermediate format (such as the assembly) to see what it's doing.

Comment: what are you doing in case `vec3(4, 0, -4)`  ??

Comment: @stefanbachert Fortunately the input is guaranteed that two components will never have equal absolute values, but good spot.

Comment: @amoffat: `I don't trust my compiler to optimize it.` Are you this terrified that the compiler might waste a cycle or two that you write everything by hand? Do you write out matrix multiplies or cross-products or texture functions by hand? If not, why is this one case so important that you can't just let the compiler do its job? And no, "bit-shifting" isn't what you'd call fast in GLSL. `I don't have access to any intermediate format to see what it's doing.` You wouldn't be able to tell if it was optimal anyway without intimate knowledge of the hardware, scheduling, and so forth.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not terrified, I'm still learning.  Right now I'm learning if doing this kind of optimization is even worth it.  I'm still new, so the only real optimization rule I know when writing shaders is: "avoid conditional branching" because "something something, thread coherency."  I'm not sure to what extent I need to hold fast to that, because I don't have the experience yet under my belt.  Btw, I love arcsynthesis!  Keep up the great work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would determ the max AND the min of all values, and then decide what is abs larger

```
ma = max(v[0], max(v[1], v[2]));
mi = min(v[0], min(v[1], v[2]));

res = abs(mi) > ma ? mi : ma;
```

If you want to get the sign, replace the last line with an if

```
if (abs(mi) > ma) {
  sign = -1;
  res = mi;
} else {
  sign = +1;
  res = ma;
}
```

However, what should happen on (0, 0, 0)? no sign?

Comment: Very clever.  I will still need to do a conditional to determine the final signed value, but I think this is as good as it gets.  Thanks!

Comment: You should change the if to check for `mi < -ma` otherwise we run into unnecessary problems when `mi = -2**(wordsize-1)`